# How can I read a file and split the text into variables?

Tags: java

I am trying to write and read data from a text file for my JTable. I am able to write the data to the text file but I am having difficulty in reading and loading the data back into the JTable.

**Write to File Method**

This method will create the text file and save the individual rows of the JTable to the file as seperate lines.

```
public void saveData() {

    try{
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("data.txt", "UTF-8");
        for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++) {
                writer.print(table.getValueAt(row, col));
                writer.print(":");
            }
            writer.println();
        }
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }      
}
```

**Read from file method**

```
public void loadData() {

    File file = new File("data.txt");
    Scanner scanner;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
               String line = scanner.nextLine();

                String[] details = line.split(":");
                String name = details[0];
                String dueDate = details[1];
                String priority = details[3];

                model.addTask(name, dueDate, priority);
                model.fireTableDataChanged();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I would like this method to read the each line and split the lines into 3 variables so that I can add it back to my JTable.

For example, data in the file is saved as follows:

`A task:None:Low`

`Task2:2, January:High`

So this would split line 1 as `A task`, `None` and `Low` and line 2 as `Task2`, `2, January` and `High`

Thanks.

Comment: What what exactly is not working, is there a stacktrace?

Comment: @CardinalSystem Umm... well the Console is saying `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3`

Comment: Time to do some debugging and printing out the contents of each line and the array obtained by splitting as it's read in.

Comment: You're splitting wrong, with the wrong regex.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `String priority = details[3];` to `String priority = details[2];`.

In Java indices start at `0`, so to access the final element `Low`, which is at the third index, you would have to use `2`.

Comment: OMG. That works. Thanks. I seriously don't know how I missed that.

Comment: @user982467 Everyone makes these mistakes now and then, I would suggest you use an [IDE](https://www.eclipse.org/home/index.php) so you won't miss this kind of stuff anymore. In an IDE you can click the Stacktrace and it will take you straight to the line that threw the exception.

Comment: I use Eclipse IDE... Guess that isn't the best one then

Comment: @user982467 Eclipse is perfectly fine, you just need to remember to view your console and follow the stacktrace back through the program. Where it says `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3`, there was probably a line after that that said something similar to `at randomClass.java:27`, if you click that is should take you straight to the line that caused the error, in this case `String priority = details[3];`.

Answer (score 2):

```
String priority = details[3];
```

Here it must be 2 and not 3 as you are getting the third element and they are numbered starting with 0.